# How to have clusters of stacked bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

So here is how my data set looks like :

```
In [1]: df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J"])

In [2]: df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J"])

In [3]: df1
Out[3]: 
          I         J
A  0.675616  0.177597
B  0.675693  0.598682
C  0.631376  0.598966
D  0.229858  0.378817

In [4]: df2
Out[4]: 
          I         J
A  0.939620  0.984616
B  0.314818  0.456252
C  0.630907  0.656341
D  0.020994  0.538303
```

**I want to have stacked bar plot for each dataframe but since they have same index, I'd like to have 2 stacked bars per index.**

I've tried to plot both on the same axes :

```
In [5]: ax = df1.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)

In [5]: ax2 = df2.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, ax = ax)
```

But it overlaps.

Then I tried to concat the two dataset first :

```
pd.concat(dict(df1 = df1, df2 = df2),axis = 1).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

but here everything is stacked

My best try is :

```
 pd.concat(dict(df1 = df1, df2 = df2),axis = 0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Which gives :

[image]

This is basically what I want, except that I want the bar ordered as

(df1,A) (df2,A) (df1,B) (df2,B) etc...

I guess there is a trick but I can't found it !

---

After @bgschiller's answer I got this :

[image]

Which is almost what I want. I would like the bar to be **clustered by index**, in order to have something visually clear.

*Bonus* : Having the x-label not redundant, something like :

```
df1 df2    df1 df2
_______    _______ ...
   A          B
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I eventually found a trick (edit: see below for using seaborn and longform dataframe):

#### Solution with pandas and matplotlib

Here it is with a more complete example :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_clustered_stacked(dfall, labels=None, title="multiple stacked bar plot",  H="/", **kwargs):
    """Given a list of dataframes, with identical columns and index, create a clustered stacked bar plot. 
labels is a list of the names of the dataframe, used for the legend
title is a string for the title of the plot
H is the hatch used for identification of the different dataframe"""

    n_df = len(dfall)
    n_col = len(dfall[0].columns) 
    n_ind = len(dfall[0].index)
    axe = plt.subplot(111)

    for df in dfall : # for each data frame
        axe = df.plot(kind="bar",
                      linewidth=0,
                      stacked=True,
                      ax=axe,
                      legend=False,
                      grid=False,
                      **kwargs)  # make bar plots

    h,l = axe.get_legend_handles_labels() # get the handles we want to modify
    for i in range(0, n_df * n_col, n_col): # len(h) = n_col * n_df
        for j, pa in enumerate(h[i:i+n_col]):
            for rect in pa.patches: # for each index
                rect.set_x(rect.get_x() + 1 / float(n_df + 1) * i / float(n_col))
                rect.set_hatch(H * int(i / n_col)) #edited part     
                rect.set_width(1 / float(n_df + 1))

    axe.set_xticks((np.arange(0, 2 * n_ind, 2) + 1 / float(n_df + 1)) / 2.)
    axe.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation = 0)
    axe.set_title(title)

    # Add invisible data to add another legend
    n=[]        
    for i in range(n_df):
        n.append(axe.bar(0, 0, color="gray", hatch=H * i))

    l1 = axe.legend(h[:n_col], l[:n_col], loc=[1.01, 0.5])
    if labels is not None:
        l2 = plt.legend(n, labels, loc=[1.01, 0.1]) 
    axe.add_artist(l1)
    return axe

# create fake dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5),
                   index=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
                   columns=["I", "J", "K", "L", "M"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5),
                   index=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
                   columns=["I", "J", "K", "L", "M"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5),
                   index=["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
                   columns=["I", "J", "K", "L", "M"])

# Then, just call :
plot_clustered_stacked([df1, df2, df3],["df1", "df2", "df3"])
```

And it gives that :

[image: multiple stacked bar plot]

You can change the colors of the bar by passing a `cmap` argument:

```
plot_clustered_stacked([df1, df2, df3],
                       ["df1", "df2", "df3"],
                       cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
```

---

#### Solution with seaborn:

Given the same df1, df2, df3, below, I convert them in a long form:

```
df1["Name"] = "df1"
df2["Name"] = "df2"
df3["Name"] = "df3"
dfall = pd.concat([pd.melt(i.reset_index(),
                           id_vars=["Name", "index"]) # transform in tidy format each df
                   for i in [df1, df2, df3]],
                   ignore_index=True)
```

The problem with seaborn is that it doesn't stack bars natively, so the trick is to plot the cumulative sum of each bar on top of each other:

```
dfall.set_index(["Name", "index", "variable"], inplace=1)
dfall["vcs"] = dfall.groupby(level=["Name", "index"]).cumsum()
dfall.reset_index(inplace=True) 

>>> dfall.head(6)
  Name index variable     value       vcs
0  df1     A        I  0.717286  0.717286
1  df1     B        I  0.236867  0.236867
2  df1     C        I  0.952557  0.952557
3  df1     D        I  0.487995  0.487995
4  df1     A        J  0.174489  0.891775
5  df1     B        J  0.332001  0.568868
```

Then loop over each group of `variable` and plot the cumulative sum:

```
c = ["blue", "purple", "red", "green", "pink"]
for i, g in enumerate(dfall.groupby("variable")):
    ax = sns.barplot(data=g[1],
                     x="index",
                     y="vcs",
                     hue="Name",
                     color=c[i],
                     zorder=-i, # so first bars stay on top
                     edgecolor="k")
ax.legend_.remove() # remove the redundant legends
```

[image: multiple stack bar plot seaborn]

It lacks the legend that can be added easily I think. The problem is that instead of hatches (which can be added easily) to differentiate the dataframes we have a gradient of lightness, and it's a bit too light for the first one, and I don't really know how to change that without changing each rectangle one by one (as in the first solution).

Tell me if you don't understand something in the code.

Feel free to re-use this code which is under CC0.

Comment: Nice ! How an this be plotted with mpld3 ?

Comment: I don't know mpdld3, but from what I understood from the doc, you just need to display it with `mpld3.display(plt.gcf())`,or something similar.

Comment: Could you do me a huge favor and put this snipplet under BSD / MIT / CC-0? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I am trying to add error bars to this, but they are shifted. Can you show how to include them?

Comment: @jrjc thanks for the great answer. In my machine it is running successfully but do not show any bar plot. It does not raise the error at all but still does not show the bar. do you have any idea?

Comment: @jrjc I would greatly appreciate it if you let me know if you have any idea, both matplot and seaborn runs but no barplot show up !

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi Try to add plt.show() at then end, or ask another question

Comment: @AndreasMueller All code posted to this site is under the CC BY-SA 3.0, you are free to re-use this code to your hearts content.

Comment: @cjnash that's not the same as any of the licenses I mentioned and will be troublesome if included in an open source library. I probably rewrote this already at some point though, this comment is 7 years old ;)

Comment: @jrjc could you point out where should be modified if I want to add error bars in the solution 1?

Comment: color was only setting right for one bar for me, updating to give it palette instead of color, with a dict of:

palette ={"df1": c[i], "df2": c[i], "df3": c[i]} works for me though!

Comment: Instead of using hatching, I calculated a transparency to mimic seaborn. Couldn't use the seaborn plot as it made annotating the patches more difficult. `rect.set_alpha(((i+1)/n_df/n_col)*0.7+0.3)` using a minimum alpha of 0.3 and scaling.

Answer (score 23):

This is a great start but I think the colors could be modified a bit for clarity. Also be careful about importing every argument in Altair as this may cause collisions with existing objects in your namespace. Here is some reconfigured code to display the correct color display when stacking the values:

[image: Altair Clustered Column Chart]

#### Import packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt
```

#### Generate some random data

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J","K"])
df2=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J","K"])
df3=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J","K"])

def prep_df(df, name):
    df = df.stack().reset_index()
    df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'values']
    df['DF'] = name
    return df

df1 = prep_df(df1, 'DF1')
df2 = prep_df(df2, 'DF2')
df3 = prep_df(df3, 'DF3')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

#### Plot data with Altair

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(

    # tell Altair which field to group columns on
    x=alt.X('c2:N', title=None),

    # tell Altair which field to use as Y values and how to calculate
    y=alt.Y('sum(values):Q',
        axis=alt.Axis(
            grid=False,
            title=None)),

    # tell Altair which field to use to use as the set of columns to be  represented in each group
    column=alt.Column('c1:N', title=None),

    # tell Altair which field to use for color segmentation 
    color=alt.Color('DF:N',
            scale=alt.Scale(
                # make it look pretty with an enjoyable color pallet
                range=['#96ceb4', '#ffcc5c','#ff6f69'],
            ),
        ))\
    .configure_view(
        # remove grid lines around column clusters
        strokeOpacity=0    
    )
```

Comment: Is it possible to have different colour sets for the different columns I, J and K?

Comment: @toryan you can use my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66150701/3896008) which gives you an option to choose different color schemes for each I,J,K. I am sure that can be done in altair as well but couldn't do it with my limited knowledge of altair :P

Comment: @grant-langseth could you point out where should be modified if I want to add error bars?

Comment: @Grant Langseth, Is there an easy way to show the values of each part of each stacked bar chart?

Comment: @Grant Langseth The `I J K` indicator marks on the horizontal axis of your figure look really nice. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve a similar appearance in my own figure?

Answer (score 9):

I have managed to do the same using pandas and matplotlib subplots with basic commands.

Here's an example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)

ax_position = 0
for concept in df.index.get_level_values('concept').unique():
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    subset = df.loc[idx[[concept], :],
                    ['cmp_tr_neg_p_wrk', 'exp_tr_pos_p_wrk',
                     'cmp_p_spot', 'exp_p_spot']]     
    print(subset.info())
    subset = subset.groupby(
        subset.index.get_level_values('datetime').year).sum()
    subset = subset / 4  # quarter hours
    subset = subset / 100  # installed capacity
    ax = subset.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, colormap="Blues",
                     ax=axes[ax_position])
    ax.set_title("Concept \"" + concept + "\"", fontsize=30, alpha=1.0)
    ax.set_ylabel("Hours", fontsize=30),
    ax.set_xlabel("Concept \"" + concept + "\"", fontsize=30, alpha=0.0),
    ax.set_ylim(0, 9000)
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 9000, 1000))
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels=range(0, 9000, 1000), rotation=0,
                       minor=False, fontsize=28)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels=['2012', '2013', '2014'], rotation=0,
                       minor=False, fontsize=28)
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(['Market A', 'Market B',
               'Market C', 'Market D'],
              loc='upper right', fontsize=28)
    ax_position += 1

# look "three subplots"
#plt.tight_layout(pad=0.0, w_pad=-8.0, h_pad=0.0)

# look "one plot"
plt.tight_layout(pad=0., w_pad=-16.5, h_pad=0.0)
axes[1].set_ylabel("")
axes[2].set_ylabel("")
axes[1].set_yticklabels("")
axes[2].set_yticklabels("")
axes[0].legend().set_visible(False)
axes[1].legend().set_visible(False)
axes[2].legend(['Market A', 'Market B',
                'Market C', 'Market D'],
               loc='upper right', fontsize=28)
```

The dataframe structure of "subset" before grouping looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 105216 entries, (D_REC, 2012-01-01 00:00:00) to (D_REC, 2014-12-31 23:45:00)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
cmp_tr_neg_p_wrk    105216 non-null float64
exp_tr_pos_p_wrk    105216 non-null float64
cmp_p_spot          105216 non-null float64
exp_p_spot          105216 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 4.0+ MB
```

and the plot like this:

[image]

It is formatted in the "ggplot" style with the following header:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Comment: Great answer, but it is harder to follow without the data to replicate. Is it possible to download the data somewhere?

Comment: could you please add sample data so this is reproducible.

Answer (score 9):

The answer by @jrjc for use of `seaborn` is very clever, but it has a few problems, as noted by the author:

1. The "light" shading is too pale when only two or three categories are needed. It makes colour series (pale blue, blue, dark blue, etc.) difficult to distinguish.
2. The legend is not produced to distinguish the meaning of the shadings ("pale" means what?)

**More importantly**, however, I found out that, because of the `groupby`statement in the code:

3. This solution works *only* if the columns are ordered alphabetically. If I rename columns `["I", "J", "K", "L", "M"]` by something anti-alphabetical (`["zI", "yJ", "xK", "wL", "vM"]`), [I get this graph instead](https://gitlab.com/ciraig/lca_standard_graphs/blob/master/demo/demoOfNeedFor_plot_grouped_stackedbars().ipynb):

[image: Stacked bar construction fails if columns are not in alphabetical order]

---

I strove to resolve these problems with the `plot_grouped_stackedbars()` function in [this open-source python module](https://gitlab.com/ciraig/lca_standard_graphs).

1. It keeps the shading within reasonable range
2. It auto-generates a legend that explains the shading
3. It does not rely on `groupby`

[image: Proper grouped stacked-bars graph with legend and narrow shading range]

It also allows for

1. various normalization options (see below normalization to 100% of maximum value)
2. the addition of error bars

[image: Example with normalization and error bars]

See [full demo here](https://gitlab.com/ciraig/lca_standard_graphs/blob/master/demo/demo_grouped_stacked_bars.ipynb). I hope this proves useful and can answer the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more succinct implementation of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060572/7758804) from Cord Kaldemeyer. The idea is to reserve as much width as necessary for the plots. Then each cluster gets a subplot of the required length.

```
# Data and imports

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(1+5*np.random.random((10,4)), dtype=int),columns=["Cluster", "Bar", "Bar_part", "Count"])
df = df.groupby(["Cluster", "Bar", "Bar_part"])["Count"].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
display(df)

# plotting

clusters = df.index.levels[0]
inter_graph = 0
maxi = np.max(np.sum(df, axis=1))
total_width = len(df)+inter_graph*(len(clusters)-1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(total_width,10))
gridspec.GridSpec(1, total_width)
axes=[]

ax_position = 0
for cluster in clusters:
    subset = df.loc[cluster]
    ax = subset.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, width=0.8, ax=plt.subplot2grid((1,total_width), (0,ax_position), colspan=len(subset.index)))
    axes.append(ax)
    ax.set_title(cluster)
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_ylim(0,maxi+1)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax_position += len(subset.index)+inter_graph

for i in range(1,len(clusters)):
    axes[i].set_yticklabels("")
    axes[i-1].legend().set_visible(False)
axes[0].set_ylabel("y_label")

fig.suptitle('Big Title', fontsize="x-large")
legend = axes[-1].legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=16, framealpha=1).get_frame()
legend.set_linewidth(3)
legend.set_edgecolor("black")

plt.show()
```

The result is the following:

[image: (not able yet to post an image directly on the site)]

Comment: is there any way to rearange the order of the groups? And the column within each group? ie. on group 1, 5,4, on group 2: 4,3,5 ?

Comment: You would have to rearrange the data itself, and slightly change the code. Before the display, do `df = df.loc[[(3, 4), (3, 3), (3, 5), (1, 5), (1, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 2)]]` and when initialising `clusters`, write `clusters = df.index.get_level_values("Cluster").drop_duplicates()`. It should do the trick.

Comment: how do you increase the font size of cluster groups (number below "Big Title")?

Comment: `ax.set_title(cluster, fontsize=32)` instead of `ax.set_title(cluster)`

Comment: how can you add hatches to the columns (along with existing colours)?

Comment: Add something like `for container in ax.containers: for patch in container.patches: patch.set_hatch(r"/")` inside the first for-loop

Answer (score 3):

We tried to do this just using matplotlib. We converted the values to cumulative values as shown below:

```
# get cumulative values
cum_val = [a[0]]
for j in range(1,len(a)):
    cum_val.append( cum_val[j-1] + a[j] )
```

We then plotted bars in descending order of height so that they are all visible. We added some hard-coded color schemes as well as it can generated sequentially from the RGB cube. The package can be installed  with

```
pip install groupstackbar
```

Then, it can be imported as used as shown below. Also, there is a function (`generate_dummy_data`) to generate a dummy.csv sample data in order to test the functionality.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import random
import groupstackbar

def generate_dummy_data():
    with open('dummy_data.csv','w') as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
        csvwriter.writerow(['Week','State_SEIR','Age_Cat','Value'])
        for i in ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3']: # 3 weeks
            for j in ['S','E','I','R']:
                for k in ['Age Cat 1', 'Age Cat 2', 'Age Cat 3', 'Age Cat 4', 'Age Cat 5']:
                    csvwriter.writerow([i,j,k, int(random.random()*100)])

generate_dummy_data()


f = groupstackbar.plot_grouped_stacks('dummy_data.csv', BGV=['State_SEIR','Week','Age_Cat'], extra_space_on_top = 30)

plt.savefig("output.png",dpi=500)
```

The `plot_grouped_stacks()` function of `groupstackbar` is reproduced below:

```
"""
Arguments: 
filename: 
  a csv filename with 4 headers, H1, H2, H3 and H4. Each one of H1/H2/H3/H4 are strings.
  the first three headers(H1/H2/H3) should identify a row uniquely 
  the fourth header H4 contains the value (H4 must be integer or floating; cannot be a string)
  .csv files without headers will result in the first row being read as headers. 
duplicates (relevant for csv inputs):
  duplicate entries imply two rows with same <H1/H2/H3> identifier. 
  In case of duplicates aggregation is performed before proceeding, both the duplicates are binned together to increase the target value 
BGV:a python list of three headers in order for stacking (Bars, Groups and Vertical Stacking)
  for example, if BGV=[H2, H1, H3], the group stack plot will be such that:
    maximum number of bars = number of unique values under column H2
    maximum number of bars grouped together horizontally(side-by-side) = number of 
                                                unique values under column H1
    maximum number of vertical stacks in any bar = number of unique values under column H2
"""
def plot_grouped_stacks(filename, BGV, fig_size=(10, 8), 
                        intra_group_spacing=0.1,
                        inter_group_spacing=10, 
                        y_loc_for_group_name=-5,
                        y_loc_for_hstack_name=5,
                        fontcolor_hstacks='blue',
                        fontcolor_groups='black',
                        fontsize_hstacks=20,
                        fontsize_groups=30,
                        x_trim_hstack_label=0,
                        x_trim_group_label=0,
                        extra_space_on_top=20 
                        ):
    

    figure_ = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
    size = figure_.get_size_inches()
    figure_.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    # sanity check for inputs; some trivial exception handlings 
    if intra_group_spacing >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables intra_group_spacing, Aborting! ")
        return 
    else:
        intra_group_spacing = intra_group_spacing*size[0]/100  # converting percentanges to inches

    if inter_group_spacing >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables inter_group_spacing, Aborting! ")        
        return 
    else:
        inter_group_spacing = inter_group_spacing*size[0]/100  # converting percentanges to inches

    
    if y_loc_for_group_name >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables inter_group_spacing, Aborting! ")        
        return 
    else:
        # the multiplier 90 is set empirically to roughly align the percentage value 
        # <this is a quick fix solution, which needs to be improved later>
        y_loc_for_group_name = 90*y_loc_for_group_name*size[1]/100  # converting percentanges to inches


    if y_loc_for_hstack_name >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables inter_group_spacing, Aborting! ")        
        return 
    else:
        y_loc_for_hstack_name = 70*y_loc_for_hstack_name*size[1]/100  # converting percentanges to inches

    if x_trim_hstack_label >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables inter_group_spacing, Aborting! ")        
        return 
    else:
        x_trim_hstack_label = x_trim_hstack_label*size[0]/100  # converting percentanges to inches

    if x_trim_group_label >= 100: 
        print ("Percentage for than 100 for variables inter_group_spacing, Aborting! ")        
        return 
    else:
        x_trim_group_label = x_trim_group_label*size[0]/100  # converting percentanges to inches




    fileread_list = []

   
    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in f:
            r = row.strip().split(',')    
            if len(r) != 4:
                print ('4 items not found @ line ', c, ' of ', filename)
                return
            else:
                fileread_list.append(r)

        
    # inputs: 
    bar_variable = BGV[0]
    group_variable = BGV[1]
    vertical_stacking_variable = BGV[2]

    first_line = fileread_list[0]
    for i in range(4):
        if first_line[i] == vertical_stacking_variable:
            header_num_Of_vertical_stacking = i
            break
    
    sorted_order_for_stacking = []
    for listed in fileread_list[1:]:  # skipping the first line
        sorted_order_for_stacking.append(listed[header_num_Of_vertical_stacking])
    sorted_order_for_stacking = list(set(sorted_order_for_stacking))
    list.sort(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    sorted_order_for_stacking_V = list(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    #####################

    first_line = fileread_list[0]
    for i in range(4):
        if first_line[i] == bar_variable:
            header_num_Of_bar_Variable = i
            break

    sorted_order_for_stacking = []
    for listed in fileread_list[1:]:  # skipping the first line
        sorted_order_for_stacking.append(listed[header_num_Of_bar_Variable])
    sorted_order_for_stacking = list(set(sorted_order_for_stacking))
    list.sort(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    sorted_order_for_stacking_H = list(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    ######################

    first_line = fileread_list[0]
    for i in range(4):
        if first_line[i] == group_variable:
            header_num_Of_bar_Variable = i
            break

    sorted_order_for_stacking = []
    for listed in fileread_list[1:]:  # skipping the first line
        sorted_order_for_stacking.append(listed[header_num_Of_bar_Variable])
    sorted_order_for_stacking = list(set(sorted_order_for_stacking))
    list.sort(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    sorted_order_for_stacking_G = list(sorted_order_for_stacking)
    #########################   

    print (" Vertical/Horizontal/Groups  ")
    print (sorted_order_for_stacking_V, " : Vertical stacking labels")
    print (sorted_order_for_stacking_H, " : Horizontal stacking labels")
    print (sorted_order_for_stacking_G, " : Group names")
    



    # +1 because we need one space before and after as well
    each_group_width = (size[0] - (len(sorted_order_for_stacking_G) + 1) *
                        inter_group_spacing)/len(sorted_order_for_stacking_G)
    
    # -1 because we need n-1 spaces between bars if there are n bars in each group
    each_bar_width = (each_group_width - (len(sorted_order_for_stacking_H) - 1) *
                      intra_group_spacing)/len(sorted_order_for_stacking_H)

    
    # colormaps 
    number_of_color_maps_needed = len(sorted_order_for_stacking_H)
    number_of_levels_in_each_map = len(sorted_order_for_stacking_V)
    c_map_vertical = {}
    
    for i in range(number_of_color_maps_needed):
        try:
            c_map_vertical[sorted_order_for_stacking_H[i]] = sequential_colors[i]
        except:
            print ("Something went wrong with hardcoded colors!\n reverting to custom colors (linear in RGB) ") 
            c_map_vertical[sorted_order_for_stacking_H[i]] = getColorMaps(N = number_of_levels_in_each_map, type = 'S')

    ## 

    state_num = -1
    max_bar_height = 0
    for state in sorted_order_for_stacking_H:
        state_num += 1
        week_num = -1
        for week in ['Week 1', 'Week 2','Week 3']:
            week_num += 1

            a = [0] * len(sorted_order_for_stacking_V)
            for i in range(len(sorted_order_for_stacking_V)):

                for line_num in range(1,len(fileread_list)):  # skipping the first line
                    listed = fileread_list[line_num]

                    if listed[1] == state and listed[0] == week and listed[2] == sorted_order_for_stacking_V[i]:
                        a[i] = (float(listed[3]))

            
            # get cumulative values
            cum_val = [a[0]]
            for j in range(1,len(a)):
                cum_val.append( cum_val[j-1] + a[j] )
            max_bar_height = max([max_bar_height, max(cum_val)])        
    

            plt.text(x=  (week_num)*(each_group_width+inter_group_spacing) - x_trim_group_label
            , y=y_loc_for_group_name, s=sorted_order_for_stacking_G[week_num], fontsize=fontsize_groups, color=fontcolor_groups)

            
            
            # state labels need to be printed just once for each week, hence putting them outside the loop
            plt.text(x=  week_num*(each_group_width+inter_group_spacing) + (state_num)*(each_bar_width+intra_group_spacing) - x_trim_hstack_label
             , y=y_loc_for_hstack_name, s=sorted_order_for_stacking_H[state_num], fontsize=fontsize_hstacks, color = fontcolor_hstacks)


            if week_num == 1:
                # label only in the first week

                for i in range(len(sorted_order_for_stacking_V)-1,-1,-1): 
                    # trick to make them all visible: Plot in descending order of their height!! :)
                    plt.bar(  week_num*(each_group_width+inter_group_spacing) +
                            state_num*(each_bar_width+intra_group_spacing), 
                            height=cum_val[i] ,
                            width=each_bar_width, 
                            color=c_map_vertical[state][i], 
                            label= state + "_" + sorted_order_for_stacking_V[i] )
            else:
                    # no label after the first week, (as it is just repetition)
                    for i in range(len(sorted_order_for_stacking_V)-1,-1,-1): 
                        plt.bar(  week_num*(each_group_width+inter_group_spacing) +
                            state_num*(each_bar_width+intra_group_spacing), 
                            height=cum_val[i] ,
                            width=each_bar_width, 
                            color=c_map_vertical[state][i])
                        
    plt.ylim(0,max_bar_height*(1+extra_space_on_top/100))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.xticks([], [])
    plt.legend(ncol=len(sorted_order_for_stacking_H))
    return figure_
```

A pictorial readMe is attached to help the user quickly figure out the parameters to the function. Please feel free to raise an issue or start a pull request. Currently the input format is .csv files with 4 columns, but pandas data frame input can be added if necessary.

https://github.com/jimioke/groupstackbar

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! In order to change the order of the bars, you should change the order in the index.

```
In [5]: df_both = pd.concat(dict(df1 = df1, df2 = df2),axis = 0)

In [6]: df_both
Out[6]:
              I         J
df1 A  0.423816  0.094405
    B  0.825094  0.759266
    C  0.654216  0.250606
    D  0.676110  0.495251
df2 A  0.607304  0.336233
    B  0.581771  0.436421
    C  0.233125  0.360291
    D  0.519266  0.199637

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```

So we want to swap axes, then reorder. Here's an easy way to do this

```
In [7]: df_both.swaplevel(0,1)
Out[7]:
              I         J
A df1  0.423816  0.094405
B df1  0.825094  0.759266
C df1  0.654216  0.250606
D df1  0.676110  0.495251
A df2  0.607304  0.336233
B df2  0.581771  0.436421
C df2  0.233125  0.360291
D df2  0.519266  0.199637

[8 rows x 2 columns]

In [8]: df_both.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
Out[8]:
              I         J
A df1  0.423816  0.094405
  df2  0.607304  0.336233
B df1  0.825094  0.759266
  df2  0.581771  0.436421
C df1  0.654216  0.250606
  df2  0.233125  0.360291
D df1  0.676110  0.495251
  df2  0.519266  0.199637

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```

If it's important that your horizontal labels show up in the old order (df1,A) rather than (A,df1), we can just `swaplevel`s again and not `sort_index`:

```
In [9]: df_both.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index().swaplevel(0,1)
Out[9]:
              I         J
df1 A  0.423816  0.094405
df2 A  0.607304  0.336233
df1 B  0.825094  0.759266
df2 B  0.581771  0.436421
df1 C  0.654216  0.250606
df2 C  0.233125  0.360291
df1 D  0.676110  0.495251
df2 D  0.519266  0.199637

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works aaaalmost as expected. I'd like to have something visually clear, here all bars are equally distributed along the x-axis, I'd like to have clustered 2 by 2. Sorry I did not mention that in the question. (I'll edit)

Answer (score 1):

Altair can be helpful here. Here is the produced plot.

[image]

#### Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from altair import *
```

#### Dataset creation

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,2),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J"])
df2=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,2),index=["A","B","C","D"],columns=["I","J"])
```

#### Preparing dataset

```
def prep_df(df, name):
    df = df.stack().reset_index()
    df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'values']
    df['DF'] = name
    return df

df1 = prep_df(df1, 'DF1')
df2 = prep_df(df2, 'DF2')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

#### Altair plot

```
Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(y=Y('values', axis=Axis(grid=False)),
                            x='c2:N', 
                            column=Column('c1:N') ,
                            color='DF:N').configure_facet_cell( strokeWidth=0.0).configure_cell(width=200, height=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did with two charts including data replication.

Initial Data:

```
      A     B    C   D
0   level1  B1  456 326
1   level1  B3  694 1345
2   level1  B2  546 1471
3   level2  B1  687 806
4   level2  B3  877 1003
5   level2  B2  790 1004
```

Set multi index

```
data = data.set_index(["A", "B"])
```

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
import os
import seaborn as sns    
matplotlib.style.use("seaborn-white")

ig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,6))
ax_position = 0
y_offset = -120 # decrease value if you want to decrease the position of data labels
for metric in data.index.get_level_values('A').unique():
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    subset = data.loc[idx[[metric], :],
                    ['C', 'D']]   
    subset = subset.groupby(
        subset.index.get_level_values('B')).sum()
    ax = subset.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, colormap="Pastel1",
                     ax=axes[ax_position])
    ax.set_title(metric, fontsize=15, alpha=1.0)
    ax.set_xlabel(metric, fontsize=15, alpha=0.0)
    ax.set_ylabel("Values", fontsize=15)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels=['B1', "B2", "B3"], rotation=0,
                       minor=False, fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 3000)
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 3000, 500), fontsize=15)
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax_position += 1
    
    for bar in ax.patches:
        ax.text(
          # Put the text in the middle of each bar. get_x returns the start
          # so we add half the width to get to the middle.
          bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
          # Vertically, add the height of the bar to the start of the bar,
          # along with the offset.
          bar.get_height() + bar.get_y() + y_offset,
          # This is actual value we'll show.
          round(bar.get_height()),
          # Center the labels and style them a bit.
          ha='center',
          color='w',
          weight='bold',
          size=12
      )

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.0, w_pad=-1.0, h_pad=0.0) # increase w_pad if you'd like to separate charts
axes[1].set_yticklabels("")
axes[1].set_ylabel("")
axes[0].legend().set_visible(False)
```

[image: result chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bar order by altering the index order (using sort in this case):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2']).sort_index(level=1).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]