# Stacked bar chart multiple binary variables with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe with about 10 binary variables and I want to plot the zero and one counts in a stacked barchart using Seaborn. Anyone can help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845857/2901002) [possible](http://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/) create stacked bar in seaborn, but really complicated.

Simplier is use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with parameter `stacked=True`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1110','1111', '0000']})

print (df)
      A
0  1110
1  1111
2  0000

#get counts of 0, 1
x = Counter([a for x in df['A'] for a in list(x)])
print (x)
Counter({'1': 7, '0': 5})

df = pd.DataFrame([x])
print (df)
   0  1
0  5  7

df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```