# Horizontal barplot grouped by column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I have a df that looks like this.

```
Education                 Food_expenditures   Mitigative_expenditures   Household_expenditures
0   Primary (incomplete)    0.549451          6.923077                  2.527473
1   Illiterate              5.000000          5.000000                  0.000000
2   Primary (completed)     2.868217          4.883721                  2.248062
4   Illiterate              5.593220          3.559322                  0.847458
5   Primary (incomplete)    3.333333          5.555556                  1.111111
```

I would like to have a horizontal bar plot that is grouped by the expenditures and then by education.
Something that looks like this (only this example is just grouped by two levels for the second part).

[image]

I also want to invert it, so group first for Education and then for expenditures. But I'm sure I can figure that out based on the first one.
I just couldn't find a good example.

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate values by `Education` by some function like `sum` or `mean` and transpose `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Education').sum().T
print (df1)

Education                Illiterate  Primary (completed)  Primary (incomplete)
variable                                                                      
Food_expenditures         10.593220             2.868217              3.882784
Household_expenditures     0.847458             2.248062              3.638584
Mitigative_expenditures    8.559322             4.883721             12.478633
```

Then use [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
df1.plot.barh()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would this also work if I want to have Education as the group? So three bars (food,household,mitigative) per education level?

Comment: @JoepHoeijmakers - So here are 9 bars grouped by 3?

Comment: @JoepHoeijmakers - Or need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787209/how-to-have-clusters-of-stacked-bars-with-python-pandas) ?

Comment: 9 bars grouped by three indeed. so for every level in my column Education, the corresponding bars for food/household/mitigative expenditures