# plot bars using python matplotlib with two different datas in the same bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to do a plot using matplotlib.pyplot with the follow characteristics

I have 4 arrais of data.

The array 1 and 2 need to be together in the same bar, but with different colors.

The array 3 and 4 need to be beside the first bar.

The results will be a graphic like this:

[image]

If I have the datas:

data_1_part_1 = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)

data_1_part_2 = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)

data_2 = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

data_3 = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)

Someone knows how can I plot this graphic?

Comment: Please include your code as a part of the question. It will help others to assist you in finding a solution.  It may help to take a look at [how to formulate a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have clusters of stacked bars with python (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787209/how-to-have-clusters-of-stacked-bars-with-python-pandas)