# How to plot groups of stacked bars from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am creating the plots this way:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df = pd.concat((data.assign(source=name) for data, name in zip([train_ss_freq_df, train_ss_freq_df], ['train', 'blind'])))                
df[df['source']=='train'].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=sns.color_palette("crest", 3),ax=ax)
df[df['source']=='blind'].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=sns.color_palette("crest", 3),ax=ax)
```

the datasets are these:

```
,H,E,C
A,0.039065342828923426,0.014685241981597963,0.026069553464677445
R,0.023860269272755627,0.011930134636377814,0.017492332484275095
N,0.012605915683318605,0.007381608358891719,0.02365233664292769
D,0.018817902999428187,0.007589540988719654,0.03285335551281385
C,0.004028694702916255,0.002729115766491657,0.004470551541300619
Q,0.01886988615688517,0.007849456776004574,0.013437646202630348
E,0.032983313406456306,0.010578572542496232,0.020975204033893018
G,0.013827519883557727,0.013437646202630348,0.04777252170296824
H,0.008733170452773302,0.006004054686281644,0.011150387274523055
I,0.020793262982793576,0.021209128242449447,0.012969797785517493
L,0.04384779331496595,0.02666735977543276,0.024899932421895307
K,0.02352237874928523,0.010084732546654884,0.021832926131933255
M,0.007797473618547591,0.004678484171128554,0.005354265218069345
F,0.01465925040286947,0.013749545147372252,0.011150387274523055
P,0.009201018869886156,0.0047304673285855385,0.03246348183188647
S,0.017856214586473983,0.013229713572802412,0.028278837656599262
T,0.015387014607267246,0.01614077039039351,0.023990227166398086
W,0.006419919945937516,0.004600509434943078,0.004418568383843634
Y,0.01268389041950408,0.012943806206789,0.011202370431980038
V,0.02139106929354889,0.032151582887144564,0.016842543016062795

,H,E,C
A,0.04221830985915493,0.014446680080482898,0.02841549295774648
R,0.02193158953722334,0.011006036217303823,0.019577464788732395
N,0.010206237424547284,0.005719315895372234,0.023712273641851106
D,0.016267605633802817,0.007223340040241449,0.03400905432595573
C,0.0037927565392354124,0.0037374245472837023,0.005960764587525151
Q,0.017751509054325956,0.0064285714285714285,0.014305835010060362
E,0.03344567404426559,0.010326961770623743,0.026398390342052314
G,0.01176056338028169,0.011066398390342052,0.05057344064386318
H,0.00698692152917505,0.005060362173038229,0.01062374245472837
I,0.02187122736418511,0.02117706237424547,0.01375251509054326
L,0.043470824949698186,0.022062374245472836,0.028118712273641853
K,0.024170020120724348,0.011036217303822938,0.024622736418511065
M,0.009476861167002013,0.004592555331991952,0.007339034205231389
F,0.01391851106639839,0.011956740442655935,0.013083501006036218
P,0.007027162977867203,0.004964788732394366,0.033591549295774646
S,0.015774647887323943,0.01119718309859155,0.030653923541247484
T,0.015020120724346076,0.014507042253521127,0.024899396378269618
W,0.004964788732394366,0.003958752515090543,0.004678068410462776
Y,0.011156941649899397,0.010789738430583501,0.011091549295774649
V,0.023586519114688127,0.02992957746478873,0.018606639839034204
```

The problem is that they're overlapping. How can I make them side by side but still in the same figure? I concatenated them in the hope of finding a way to separate them by "source", but I haven't found the right argument to do so.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the plot must be grouped and clustered, there is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845857/7758804). However, it's easier to set a multi-index and plot individual bars.
- Plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and use `kind='bar'` or `kind='barh'`.

```py
# given the two dataframes as train and blind
# combine them into a single dataframe
df = pd.concat((data.assign(source=name) for data, name in zip([train, blind], ['train', 'blind'])))

# reset, set, and sort the index
dfp = df.reset_index().set_index(['index', 'source']).sort_index()

# plot the bars with kind='bar' or kind='barh'
ax = dfp.plot(kind='barh', width=0.75, stacked=True, color=sns.color_palette("crest", 3), figsize=(9, 15))
```

[image]

### DataFrame Views

#### `df.head()`

```
          H         E         C source
A  0.039065  0.014685  0.026070  train
R  0.023860  0.011930  0.017492  train
N  0.012606  0.007382  0.023652  train
D  0.018818  0.007590  0.032853  train
C  0.004029  0.002729  0.004471  train
```

#### `dfp.head(6)`

```
                     H         E         C
index source                              
A     blind   0.042218  0.014447  0.028415
      train   0.039065  0.014685  0.026070
C     blind   0.003793  0.003737  0.005961
      train   0.004029  0.002729  0.004471
D     blind   0.016268  0.007223  0.034009
      train   0.018818  0.007590  0.032853
```