# Grouped Stacked Bar Charts in Python (Seaborn or Matplotlib)

Tags: bar-chart, combinations, group, stacked

Consider that i have the following Dataframe. The last column CumSumPerGroup, represent the sum per group of unique combination of Status_Group + Department.

| Status_Group | Department | Status | Variable | CumSumPerGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | DeptA | Accepted | 168 | 168 |
| A | DeptA | Approved | 68 | 236 |
| A | DeptA | New | 153 | 389 |
| A | DeptA | Pending Approval | 51 | 440 |
| A | DeptA | WIP | 11 | 451 |
| B | DeptA | Closed | 127 | 127 |
| B | DeptA | Completed | 3 | 130 |
| B | DeptA | Rejected | 20 | 150 |
| A | DeptB | Accepted | 45 | 45 |
| A | DeptB | Approved | 32 | 77 |
| A | DeptB | New | 7 | 84 |
| B | DeptB | Closed | 71 | 71 |
| B | DeptB | Completed | 1 | 72 |
| B | DeptB | Unsolved | 1 | 73 |
| A | DeptC | Approved | 3 | 3 |

What i am looking to do have **Department** values on **X-axis**, **Grouped by Status_Group** and **Stacked by Status**. see figure:
[What i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9GFi.png)

Solution Attempt:

Following the solution that was provided here: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787209/how-to-have-clusters-of-stacked-bars),I modified the code as follows:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(11,8))    
for i, g in enumerate(df1.groupby("Status")):
    ax = sns.barplot(data=g[1],
                     x= "Department",
                     y="CumSumPerGroup",
                     hue="Status_Group",
                     color=colors[i],
                     zorder=-i, # so first bars stay on top
                     edgecolor="k")
    for i in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(i,)
```

My output seem to keep only the first Department.
[Image obtained from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kS3N.png).

Any help is highly appreciated